# How to find a file in the subfolder?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a script that uses icons on buttons. When I leave icon.gif in the folder with the script the icons can be found without an error. But I want to keep these icons in myicons folder and use them from that folder. So the structure would be like this: myscript_folder/myicons/icon_1.gif

I have a variable that keeps the path to icons, but as you've guessed the variable has only 'icon.gif' in it.

How do I add a path to "myicons" folder to this variable which is os independent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `join` function from the [`os.path`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html) module. This module comes in different versions for different operating systems, each using the respective file separators, etc.

```
import os.path
os.path.join("myicons", "icon_1.gif")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, which is very same as tobias_k's reply.

```
import os
base_dir = r"path/to/your/myscript_folder"
print os.path.join(base_dir, "myicons", "icon_1.gif")
```